# How to add array of strings to a queue with non standard class?

Tags: java, queue

I have been given a queue

```
private static Queue<CarStats> Carcatalogue = new LinkedList<CarStats>()
```

Here the class CarStats has already been defined seperately.

Now i have a string array of Car models i.e.

```
String[] availableCars = {... list of Car model names.. }
```

which i need to add to the Queue. But i am unable to due to class type mismatch.

How can i add a standard datatype i.e. String to a user defined class queue?

Sorry i am new to Java, any help will be much appreciated.

~Neo~

Comment: `How can i add a standard datatype i.e. String to a user defined class queue?` you can't, what you probably want is to convert string into CarStats somehow

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `String` into a `CarStats`. Here is a small example using Java 8:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] models = new String[] {"A3", "A45", "Cupra"};
    Queue<CarStats> carCatalogue = new LinkedList<>();

    Arrays.stream(models)
            .map(CarStats::new)
            .forEach(carCatalogue::add);
}

static class CarStats {
    String model;
    public CarStats(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```